# Immediate one time task with Quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using a [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org) to build a clustered ThreadPool and I have number of tasks that run at various times.   What is the best way to run 1 task immanently and only once on the clustered ThreadPool.  I know I can set the task to a high priority.  But what is the best way to register a "one shot" task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I feel like I must be missing something, or maybe you just overlooked this bit in the docs:

`public SimpleTrigger(String name, String group, Date startTime, Date endTime, int repeatCount, long repeatInterval)`

---

```
SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger("myTrigger",
                                            null,
                                            new Date(),
                                            null,
                                            0,
                                            0L);
```

Comment: repeatInterval cannot be zero or the SimpleTrigger will throw a org.quartz.SchedulerException during validation.

Comment: This doesn't work for quartz 2.2.1. i get an error saying cannot instantiate SimpleTrigger

Answer (score 18):

You can also use the [TriggerBuilder](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/TriggerBuilder.html) class to make life a little bit easier.  It's similar to what was posted before, just a little cleaner.

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
    .startNow()
    .build();
```

Comment: This works for quartz 2.2.1 to fire a job only once.

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to add misfire instructions to this trigger?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to trigger an one-shot for a pre-registered job:

```
Scheduler sched = ...
scheduler.triggerJob(jobKey);
```